# What should be the temperature in the star core center for helium to not be stable so only fermion soup is present?

Tags: plasma-physics, sun, fusion

What should be the temperature in the star core center for helium to not be stable so only fermion soup is present? Of course, then there should be a distance from that center for fusion to be possible to build heavier elements.

Comment: What do you mean by "undo the fusion"? Are you asking what is the necessary temperature to start nuclear fusion? (below which the core of the star eventually becomes a degenerate "fermion soup")

Comment: @Prallax Just the temperature that would smash helum nuclei back to protons...the temperature that would bring helium cores enough energy to fission just by collisions.

Comment: @Prallax Just too hot for helium to be stable...

Comment: Okok, edit it to the question (comments might always be deleted). I'm writing an answer, but I can spoil that the temperature is very high and this doesn't  happen in most stars unless they are about to explode

Comment: What is the binding energy of helium expressed in Kelvin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Binding energy of the nuclei**

When helium nuclei smash together, they don't usually go back to protons. In general, when small nuclei collide they tend to fuse and form bigger nuclei, not to divide. The reason can be understood by looking at this figure, which represents the average binding energy per nucleon as a function of atomic number.

[image]

If small nuclei *fuse* together, their average binding energy *increases*: they become more stable and release the excess energy mostly in the form of high energy photons. This is crucial, because stars can avoid collapsing under gravitational attraction only because of the enormous pressure of the photons emitted during nuclear fusion.

For bigger nuclei the situation is the opposite. They become more stable by *fission*, by breaking in smaller parts. This is why we use uranium fission in nuclear energy plants.

The middle ground is $^{56}$Fe. It is the most stable nucleus. It is not possible to extract energy from it neither by fission nor by fusion. As a consequence, it is the heaviest element a star can produce by nuclear burning. Going further is not energetically convenient.

**Increasing the temperature of helium**

Imagine you have a star that has burned all the hydrogen in the core. The core is now composed mainly of helium. The core of star is being compressed by gravity and its temperature is rising. If the star is massive enough, the temperature of the core will eventually reach about $10^8 K$. At this point the helium nuclei smash together so fast and so frequently that the [triple alpha process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process) can happen. Helium fuses to form carbon.

After a short (astronomical) time, all the helium in the core is consumed and the star may (or may not, depending on the mass) proceed to produce even heavier elements.

**So, can ever the helium go back to protons and neutrons?**

If the star is very massive it could go on fusing elements until it gets to iron. As already said, iron is the stopping point, the star cannot go further. When the iron core starts to collapse under its own gravity, it cannot start to fuse into heavier elements. The energy released during the collapse may heat the core above $10^{10}K$. At this point the photons are so energetic that they start to *photodisintegrate* iron. When a high energy photons hits an iron nucleus it can knock out alpha particles (helium nuclei) from it.

At even higher temperatures also the helium nuclei can be photodisintegrated into protons and neutron. Photodisintegration does not *produce* energy, but *requires* energy. This processes suck energy from the star that starts collapsing even faster, leading to a runaway thermonuclear reaction that will shortly lead to a supernova explosion.

The OP was asking about the temperature at which helium is destroyed. It is not easy to estimate. One cannot just convert the binding energy of the helium nucleus into kelvin. The correct result is given by solving the equations of nuclear-statistical-equilibrium. The temperature will strongly depend on many factors, the most relevant ones are

- the density of the core
- the neutron/proton ratio

As an example, judging by figure 36.3 of the Kippenhahn it seems that if the proton/neutron ratio is equal to 1, and the density is between $10^5$ and $10^6 g\ cm^{-3}$, photodisintegration of helium happens at temperatures between  $10^{15}$ and $10^{16}K$.